# How to convert Java project into Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a java project that uses HTTPClient and Java JSON to make HTTP calls. Currently, I am distributing it as a Jar file (not a Runnable Jar File). When I integrate with another application and use the jar I get the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody
```

I am not quite sure what is causing this. One solution I was considering was converting my Java project into a Maven project and distributing it as such. How can I do that? Is that the best way?

Comment: It really seems to be a dependency problem. Maven would be a good way to solve this. But explaining how to do it would be a way to long answer for this site. There are a lot of beginner tutorials on Maven out there. You should consult those first and come back if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

To convert Java project to Maven in Eclipse,

`Right Click On Project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you move your source from /src to /src/main/java and place an XML file named pom.xml in the root of your project.
The POM file then contains  tags that detail what other libraries your project depends upon. To find the 'dependency' tags you need to include in your pom go to maven central and search for the thing you need [like this for example](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chttpclient)

click on the version you want and just find the tag and paste it into your POM. if all you're doing is building a JAR your pom will be fairly simple containing only the dependencies and the version information.
Once done, install maven and run "mvn clean install" in the project folder (maven must be on your 'path').

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using Eclipse so I did right click > configure > convert to maven. I have a pom file. I did maven clean and maven install and it built properly. Now how can I distribute the project as a jar? Do I just normally go Export > Export as jar?

Comment: this other application that is using your jar... is it also a maven project and are you building that project on the same machine?

Comment: Its not a Maven project. And yes its on the same machine.

Comment: I added all the dependencies too

Comment: can you convert the other project?

Comment: No but I don't think I need to, do i?

Comment: it would make it all much easier if you did, then you could just add your jar as a dependency. alternatively you can use the maven shade plugin to create a "fat jar' containing all the httpclient dependencies etc.